# Limite máximo marcadores Google Maps

Tags: php, javascript, html, google-maps

Tenho a aplicação abaixo, que adiciona marcadores no mapa conforme os endereços passados, porém me parece que está com um limite máximo. Chega somente a marcar 10 pontos, mas existe mais que 10 endereços passados. Alguem saberia me dizer o por que e como resolvo esse caso ? Preciso de um limite um pouco maior. Há como obter isso ? E como ?

**Código:**

```
<?php
include_once 'connection_open.php';
include_once 'DAO/RoteiroDAO.php';
include_once 'controller/RoteiroCont.php';
include_once 'model/Roteiro.php';

$roteiro = new RoteiroControle($conn);

$romaneio = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'romaneio');

if ($romaneio) {
    $romaneio = $romaneio;
} else {
    $romaneio = 'null';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Roteiros</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container_12">
            <form action="index" method="POST">
                <fieldset>
                    <label>Romaneio:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="romaneio" value="<?php
                    if ($romaneio == 'null') {
                        echo '';
                    } else {
                        echo $romaneio;
                    }
                    ?>"/>
                    <label>Placa:</label>
                    <input type="text" name= "placa" value=""/>
                    <br>
                    <button type="submit">Filtrar</button>
                </fieldset>
            </form>

            <?php if ($romaneio != 'null') { ?>
                <table class="tableModif">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Romaneio</th>
                            <th>Placa</th>
                            <th>Cte</th>
                            <th>Data Saida</th>
                            <th>Endereço</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php foreach ($roteiro->ListaRoteiro($romaneio) as $dados) { ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $dados->getRomaneio(); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $dados->getPlaca(); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $dados->getCte(); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo ($roteiro->FormataData($dados->getDtSaidaRomaneio())); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $dados->getEndereco(); ?></td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            <?php } ?>

            <br>

            <div class="map" id="map" style="height: 500px; width: 100%;"></div>

            <br><br>

        </div>

        <script src="js/gmaps.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/markers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
        <script>
            $(function () {

                //Definir o centro do mapa [endereço + elm div]
                initMap('Av. Paulista, 500, São Paulo, SP', 'map');

                <?php foreach ($roteiro->ListaRoteiro($romaneio) as $dados) { ?>

                    //Adicionar marcadores  [endereço + descricao html)
                    addMarker('<?php echo $dados->getEndereco(); ?>', '<?php echo $dados->getEndereco(); ?>');

                <?php } ?>
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

A função **addMarker** que chamo do arquivo `markers.js` é essa:

```
function addMarker(address, html){
    GMaps.geocode({
        address: address,
        callback: function (results, status) {
            if (status == 'OK') {
                var latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
                if (html == "") {
                    html = address;
                }
                lat = latlng.lat();
                lng = latlng.lng();
                var icon = "icons/m1.png";
                map.addMarker({
                    lat: lat,
                    lng: lng,
                    icon: icon,
                    //title: address,
                    infoWindow: {
                        content: html
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    })
}
```

**Saída:**

Destes abaixo mostra no mapa somente os 10 primeiros endereços.

```
$(function () {

  initMap('Av. Paulista, 500, São Paulo, SP', 'map');

  addMarker('RUA SAO FRANCISCO DE SALLES 191 Ap 96 - CENTRO - DIADEMA - SP', '');                
  addMarker('RUA PROFESSOR EVANDRO CAIAFA ESQUIVEL 235 Apto 5 - CENTRO - DIADEMA - SP', '');              
  addMarker('TUPIRITAMA 353 - AMERICANOPOLIS - SAO PAULO - SP', '');
  addMarker('BAEPENDY 595 - CAMPANARIO - DIADEMA - SP', '');
  addMarker('AV MOINHO FABRINI 339 - INDEPENDENCIA - SAO BERNARDO DO CAMPO - SP', '');
  addMarker('AVENIDA PIRAPORINHA 540 Bl yel - PLANALTO - SAO BERNARDO DO CAMPO - SP', '');
  addMarker('AVENIDA WINSTON CHURCHILL 1477 Cond - RUDGE RAMOS - SAO BERNARDO DO CAMPO - SP', '');
  addMarker('RUA SARMENTO DE BEIRES- 421  - JARDIM PORTUGAL - SAO BERNARDO DO CAMPO - SP', '');
  addMarker('RUA PAPA PAULO VI-200  - SANTA TEREZINHA - SAO BERNARDO DO CAMPO - SP', '');
  addMarker('RUA SERRA DO PILAR-129  - COOPERATIVA - SAO BERNARDO DO CAMPO - SP', '');
  addMarker('AVENIDA SENADOR VERGUEIRO 1310 Apto - PINHEIROS - SAO PAULO - SP', '');
  addMarker('RUA LEILA GONCALVES-481  - ANCHIETA - SAO BERNARDO DO CAMPO - SP', '');
  addMarker('AVENIDA GETULIO VARGAS 648 Casa c - VILA BAETA NEVES - SAO BERNARDO DO CAMPO - SP', '');
  addMarker('RUA PAULINO DE ABREU 039 casa 3 - FERRAZOPOLIS - SAO BERNARDO DO CAMPO - SP', '');
  addMarker('AVENIDA CAMINHO DO MAR 2427 Apt. - RUDGE RAMOS - SAO BERNARDO DO CAMPO - SP', '');
  addMarker('AV PEREIRA BARRETO 2444 - TAMBORE - BARUERI - SP', '');
  addMarker('RUA JORGE CHAMMAS-272  - VILA AMERICA - SANTO ANDRE - SP', '');
  addMarker('MELVIN JONES-74  - VILA BASTOS - SANTO ANDRE - SP', '');
  addMarker('RUA ADOLFO BASTOS 1239 sala - VILA BASTOS - SANTO ANDRE - SP', '');
});
```

Comment: É limite da própria API do Google Maps.

Comment: Nesse link tem uma resposta, que o cara colocou 250 marcadores http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example - não tem como adaptar meu código para isso ?

Comment: Eu uso api do google maps e apresento quantos markers vierem, sem limites, não precisei setar nada. Tem certeza que tem mais de 10 resultados mesmo? Você também pode colocar uma key para ver se é esse o problema <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=SUA_CHAVE_AQUI"></script>.

Comment: Pior que eu tenho certeza, pois na saída possui mais que 10 endereços. E já usei com a key e da no mesmo.

Comment: Se vc der um console.log(status) e console.log(result) dentro do callback e antes do if(status == 'OK') da function addMarker ele printa os 10 resultados ou todos?

Comment: @André Vicente Continua printando todos os resultados. Porém no mapa só marca os 10 primeiros.

Comment: Cara faz um teste, tenta criar um delay entre a criação dos pontos, você pode usar o `setTimeout` e ir aumentando gradativamente o tempo para que eles não iniciem juntos, exemplo: setTimeout(function() {addMarker('RUA SAO FRANCISCO', ''); }, 200); dai o próximo ao invés de 200 você colocar 400 e assim vai...

Comment: @JuniorNunes Opa, deu resultado. Setei manual, funcionou dando um delay em cada um. Como faço isso agora dinâmico como está no meu código ?

Comment: @Kevin.F eu preciso saber em que parte você chama e alimenta as funções addMarker, pode postar o código?

Comment: @JuniorNunes Eu alimento ai na primeira parte do código que postei só rolar para baixo.

Comment: Beleza, vou responder!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo que parece a API do Google limita as marcações quando se tenta fazer várias de uma vez só.

Você vai ter que colocar um delay entre cada chamada da função addMarker, você pode aproveitar seu loop pra fazer isso, assim:

```
<?php foreach ($roteiro->ListaRoteiro($romaneio) as $i => $dados) { ?>

      setTimeout(function() {
          addMarker('<?php echo $dados->getEndereco(); ?>', '<?php echo $dados->getEndereco(); ?>');
      }, 400*parseInt("<?php echo $i; ?>"));

<?php } ?>
```

OBS.: Caso você tenha muitos pontos, e leve muito tempo pra carregar você pode tentar diminuir o delay alterando o 200 no `setTimeout`, mas teste para ter a certeza de que está carregando todos sem problemas.

Você pode testar essa alternativa também que vai colocar um delay de 10 em 10 chamadas de função:

```
<?php foreach ($roteiro->ListaRoteiro($romaneio) as $i => $dados) { ?>

      setTimeout(function() {
          addMarker('<?php echo $dados->getEndereco(); ?>', '<?php echo $dados->getEndereco(); ?>');
      }, 400*parseInt("<?php echo floor($i/10); ?>"));

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Deu certo, no meu caso são 18 pontos se deixo o `setTimeout` em 200 ele mostra somente 12 pontos, tive que aumentar para 400. Por enquanto está viavel creio que não passe de 20 pontos.

Comment: Acho que o delay tem que ser um pouco maior mesmo, vou editar a resposta!

Comment: 10 o que? segundos ou milissegundos, no seu código é 400 milissegundos, então de 400ms em 400ms ele chama a função com os novos dados. Se você coloca de 10ms em 10ms, vai ficar muito rápido e ele vai bugar.

Comment: Funciona só que preciso aumentar ainda mais os milissegundos. Com 400 não mostra tudo.

Comment: Entendo, faz essa última modificação: `floor($i/10)`, e dai tu calcula o que vai valer mais a pena pra execução do seu programa

Answer (score 0):

Jovem, comenta o IF do callback e veja se o resultado continua o mesmo. Se exibir todas as entradas, avisa que tentamos resolver a partir daí.

```js
  //    if (status == 'OK') {
            var latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
            if (html == "") {
                html = address;
            }
            lat = latlng.lat();
            lng = latlng.lng();
            var icon = "icons/m1.png";
            map.addMarker({
                lat: lat,
                lng: lng,
                icon: icon,
                //title: address,
                infoWindow: {
                    content: html
                }
            });
        //}
```

Comment: O resultado continua o mesmo.